# (OSX Bash) Can't mount or cd to external USB device (Camera)

Tags: macos, bash, usb, file-transfer

Tried the usual suspects

```
system_profiler SPUSBDataType
```

can see the camera listed under USB 2.0 Bus:

```
ioreg -p IOUSB -w0 | sed 's/[^o]*o //; s/@.*$//' | grep -v '^Root.*'
```

gives me just the camera device name

but

```
mount
```

I don't see the USB device.
How can I cd to this USB device? 
My goal is to copy a file from the camera to the desktop using BASH commands.

Comment: Does `diskutil list` show your device? [source](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/107956)

Comment: Nope. Just the internal HD with partitions /dev/disk0 (internal, physical):

Comment: You probably have a hardware problem. (Either your port is broken, your cord is broken, or you plugged it in wrong.)

Comment: You should collect traces from `dmesg` executed with elevated privileges in a terminal. It is likely to announce any issue. Otherwise check that your camera has USB mass storage feature and that it is activated.